# span with onclick event inside a tag

Tags: html, css

Sample code

```
<a href="page" style="text-decoration:none;display:block;">
    <span onclick="hide()">Hide me</span>
</a>
```

Since the **a** tag is over the span is not possible to click it. I try **z-index** but that didnt work

Comment: This is just a simple sample code :D there is another stuff inside the a tag. I want to hide the hole thing

Comment: So you want to hide the span when clicking the hyperlink. Am I right?

Comment: noo the hide function will hide the hole a tag. There is a loop that shows 10 . And i use .closest().fadeOut(); but i cant click the span tag because of the a tag

Comment: give some animation for your answer

Comment: I love you dude, that's awesome question.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
<a href="http://the.url.com/page.html">
    <span onclick="hide(); return false">Hide me</span>
</a>
```

This is the easiest solution.

Comment: Works great. No need to set style for a-tag

Comment: Any idea doesn't this work if the function that is being fired by the `onclick` is defined inside `window.onload`?

Comment: Lovely solution, even that doesn't need to `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: works fine for me too! Could some one explaine to me why this solution actually works?

Answer (score 11):

When you click on `hide me`, both **a** and **span** clicks are triggering. Since the page is redirecting to another, you cannot see the working of `hide()`

You can see this for more clarification

http://jsfiddle.net/jzn82/

Answer (score 5):

Fnd the answer.

I have use some styles inorder to achive this.

```
<span 
   class="pseudolink" 
   onclick="location='https://jsfiddle.net/'">
Go TO URL
</span>

.pseudolink { 
   color:blue; 
   text-decoration:underline; 
   cursor:pointer; 
   }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mafais/bys46d5w/

Answer (score 0):

use **onmouseup**

try something like this

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function hide(){
        document.getElementById('span_hide').style.display="none";
        }
        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
        <a href="page" style="text-decoration:none;display:block;">
        <span   onmouseup="hide()" id="span_hide">Hide me</span>
        </a>
        </body>
        </html>
```

EDIT:

```
          <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $("a").click(function () { 
         $(this).fadeTo("fast", .5).removeAttr("href"); 
        });
        });
        function hide(){
        document.getElementById('span_hide').style.display="none";
        }
        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
        <a href="page.html" style="text-decoration:none;display:block;" onclick="return false" >
        <span   onmouseup="hide()" id="span_hide">Hide me</span>
        </a>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I must be onclick since the span tag is for delete a message

Comment: you don't want other action,only for delete message

Comment: yes only for delete and will hide the hole message from the page

Comment: well that wont work since both of theme has to be available for clicking. If the user click on the link it will redirect him to the message page and if he click that span to delete it. And someone can by mistake to hover the span and will the delete it. And the href is dinamic with ids for the messages

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a tag to click it. `onclick` event already do this.
Just give an `id` to your span and hide it with javascript like this.

```
<span id="should_hide" onclick="hide()">Hide me</span>


<script>
function hide(){
document.getElementById("should_hide").style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use jQuery to get the results that you're looking for.  You wouldn't need to use an anchor tag at that point but if you did it would look like:

```
<a href="page" style="text-decoration:none;display:block;">

<span onclick="hide()">Hide me</span>

</a>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' /
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('span').click(function(){
           $(this).hide();
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/Bdqv7/

Comment: if i edit your code and ad a path in the href when the span is click i get {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Comment: then sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: What do you actually want when you click the hyperlink? I am redirecting you to google. All you have to do is redirect him to a page of you own choice

Comment: noo look there is div that is inside a tag. if the user click the on the div it will redirect him to the page of the PM but in that div there is a span tag and when is click it will delete the message.But since they all are inside the a tag it dosent work..